# How do I use the CloudBees ApplicationStore from Play?

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloudbees

CloudBees have an ApplicationStore (http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/AppSessionStores), I was wondering how I can access it from Play 2.1.x. Please share your experience, if any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SessionStore is design to replicate Servlet-API HttpSession on the cluster, for a non-servlet based application you could reuse it as a memcache service (using adequate memcache client integrated in your application) and injecting configuration parameters. This probably then is simpler/safer to rely on memcachier service, that is dedicated to memcache and offers a free 25Mb instance